# Ref is not a prop, even when I am using forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am trying to access all refs in components within the navigation component.

here is my app.jsx code :

```
function App() {
  const observerRefs = {
    aboutRef: useRef(null),
    headerRef: useRef(null),
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation ref={observerRefs} />
      <Header ref={observerRefs.headerRef} />
      <About ref={observerRefs.aboutRef} />
      <Courses />
      <Reviews />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and here is my navigation component:

```
const Navigation = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { headerRef, aboutRef } = ref;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(headerRef.current);
    console.log(aboutRef.current);
  }, [headerRef, aboutRef]);
```

I still have the warning I tried many different ways but problem still remains.
any help appreciated. thanks

using forwarRef in all components.
using different names to pass refs as props